# How to have a model ignore a predictor if it contains a NA value?

Tags: r

So I have a model like

```
glm(y~a+b+c+d, df)
```

if 'a' has a NA in the observation, I want it to automatically adjust the model to

```
glm(y~b+c+d, df)
```

just for that observation.

Comment: In the documentation of `glm` there is a description about the argument `na.action`. Does this help?

Comment: @user1981275 I tried na.omit, but it seems to omit the whole row and not return anything.

Comment: @user2745630 are you sure that makes sense?

Comment: If you want to study up there is a huge literature on 'imputation' of missing values. It's much too large for discussion here. Bottom line: you need something in the data matrix to make the mechanics of regression work. If you want a methods that makes inferences with missings in the data look at tree-based procedures.

Comment: @SimonO101 After fitting a glm() with na.omit, when I use predict.glm() on a new data, it would return NA as response whenever I have any NA's in the predictors.

Comment: @user2745630 And that's sensible.

Comment: If you are truly committed to this _type_ of thing, then you might be more interested in tree models, as in the package **rpart**. Recursive partitioning models like that provide the option of using "surrogate splits" in the case that the primary one has a missing value for a particular observation.

Comment: I think that this corresponds to replacing `NA` values by in the predictors by zero ...

Comment: see the `{naniar}` package for tools to impute stuff..